# aws cp from s3 - how can I not download files as binary?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to download from s3 to my local machine to inspect files. I am running the following command:

`aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/path/to/my/files dest-dir --recursive`

All the files I download are binary, even though in s3 their content type is listed as non-binary types like `text/html`. Why might this be? Can I download the files as plain text?

Comment: What is telling you they're downloading as binary?

Comment: The test/html content type is for when the file is published via the web.  The `aws s3 cp` command is going to download the file byte-for-byte from s3 to your local computer.